# Copying columns in Excel from sheet1 to sheet2 without having to cut and paste

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

How do you copy "sheet1, column a" onto "sheet2" without using cut and paste?

I have tried using a basic `=sheet1!A1` formula, and this almost works; however, I have to add and remove data from "sheet1, column a", and as a result, on "sheet 2", the cell only references the cell originally at `A1` and changes up and down depending on where I've added columns or rows to sheet1. It won't automatically add the new data onto "sheet2' unless I re-cut and paste the column.

For example, if I add a column to the left of the data in column A on sheet1, the formula on sheet2 will automatically update to `=sheet1!B1`. I want the formula to still refer to the cell `A1` though. How can I accomplish this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following function for a cell to keep its reference even when the target is moved:

```
=INDIRECT("sheet1!a1")
```

Comment: You got it!  Deleted my answer cause you were right!